# hyperlinks with gwt

Tags: gwt, hyperlink

I am new to GWT, I would like to use hyperlinks where I would like to redirect the user to another form.

My question is that , creating hyperlinks are easy, but how do I use them ?? addClickListener seems to be deprecated, is there any other way to go around this ?

Update 1
I have implemented the Hyper link code as follows :

```
  Hyperlink link0 = new Hyperlink("Show Boxes","showbox");
  History.addValueChangeHandler(this);
  History.fireCurrentHistoryState();
  public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
  String eventValue=event.getValue();
  if(eventValue.equals("showbox")){
     showBox();
  } 
}
```

With this I see that the form corresponding to one hyperlink is visible, but this form is not closed and another for is not being opened when I click one another hyperlink. 
I am using DockPanel to display the form in the East direction. The forms for all the hyperlinks are just being displayed one below the other.

Any comments/suggestions for the same ?

Thanks,
Bhavya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Anchor.addClickHandler() method!

```
Anchor a = new Anchor("text");
a.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
   // etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the another form is within your GWT application, then you should consider using [`Hyperlink`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html). In constructor you provide a history token which is pushed to [`History`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html) object when link is clicked. You just need to handle event that a history token has changed. It decouples navigation events from your logic. This will also make your application aware of back-forward and allows users save bookmarks to specific state (form in your case). [`Anchor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) is intended more for external links.

See it described in [Coding Basics - History](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) .

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a [HyperLink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html) with a history token:

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("link to foo", "foo");
```

In above example, "foo" is the history token.

Then you should register your value change handler on [History](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html) object, like

```
History.addValueChangeHandler(myValueChangeHandler);
```

In your value change handler, you will need to read in the current token using `event.getValue()`.

```
class MyValueChangeHandler implements ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
      public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        //get the new value of history token
        //clicking on above example link will return "foo" here
        String historyToken = event.getValue();
      }
}
```

What does the value of history token means is up to your application to decide. For example you can maintain a simple Map between history tokens and the view that should be rendered. In more sophisticated applications you can encode more details into the token -- like initial state of the form that should be displayed.